# Mapping protein refseq to Gene ID

Tags: gene, genome, phylogenetics, proteomics, refseq

I have a protein refseq (eg, NP_000029). How can I get the corresponding gene ID (ag, APC) from NCBI using an R package?

Comment: Hi @ElizaGanguly Is  efetch not appropriate here?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the [reutils](https://github.com/gschofl/reutils) package, which provides an API to NCBI's [E-utilities](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25500/). Here's an example for your specific question:

```r
install.packages("reutils")
library(reutils)

# Get universal identifier
uid <- esearch("NP_000029", db = "gene")
# Fetch summary
sm <- esummary(uid, db = "gene")
# Extract specific tag
sm$xmlValue("//Name")
```